# iOS notification custom actions (buttons) -- best practices of handling errors when no GUI

Tags: ios, error-handling, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, notification-action

I have an iOS messaging app with custom notification actions (buttons that are shown when the notification is expanded on iOS 10+). Some actions need to trigger a REST call to my server without launching the app UI (`UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground` is omitted in options). Naturally the REST call may fail, but I have no GUI to reflect this to the user. What are the best practices of handling errors in such situation?

Options I could think of:

1. Show a local notification detailing the error.
2. Retry with exponential backoff in background mode.
3. Record the error and show an alert the next time the app is launched.
4. Use `UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground` after all and show an alert.

None of these seem good to me, so I wanted to ask if anyone has come with a better solution. This seems to be a common issue in messaging apps.